# When using EventEmitter is there a way to prevent subsequent handlers from being invoked?

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

Let's say I have multiple handlers to some event and want to intercept the whole queue and cancel it if the certain condition is met. Is it possible to do with NodeJS EventEmitter?

Comment: What's your case exactly? EventEmitter likely has to be extended.

Comment: Yeah. I checked the source so basically there's no other way around.